# Are HTA files a poor choice for GUI?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, frontend, hta, obsolete

I've read a few posts that state Microsoft is stopping support for HTA files or something, which leads me to question my choice of using .hta files for a project I'm working on.

The HTAs being used contain simple javascript, css and html code. The actual "engine" of the software I'm creating is created using a commercial software. The HTAs are just to provide a pretty front-end for users.

What are the limitations of doing so? Is there a better alternative or am I OK for the next 5+ years?

I like HTAs since they allow me to easily design a GUI using CSS/HTML... and then add some simple scripts (java/jquery) as needed.

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The basic limitations of continued use are if Microsoft stops supporting them as well as the lack for cross platform support. I found the following article and subsequent comments somewhat useful http://clintberry.com/2013/html5-apps-desktop-2013/.